# Unexpected output from function

Tags: c, linux

I was writing a function for finding **character** from a given **string**:

Test.c file is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int findIndex(char *array, char search)
{
    int count=0;
    char test;
    int check = 0, repeat;

    if(search == ',')
        repeat = rand()%10;

    else
        repeat = rand()%11;

    while((test = array[count]) != NULL)
    {
        if(test == search)
        {

            if(check == repeat)
                return count;

          check++;
        }

        count++;
    }

}

int main()
{
    char sc[] = "cn:Y,x509UniqueIdentifier:Y,pseudonym:Y,name:Y,l:Y,street:Y,state:Y,postalAddress:Y,postalCode:Y,telephoneNumber:Y,emailAddress:Y";
    char testchar;  

    printf("Enter the search character: ");
    testchar = getc(stdin);

    printf("The search char found at: %d position.\n",findIndex(sc,testchar));

    fflush(stdin);

    while(testchar != 'N')
    {
        printf("The search char found at: %d posotion.\n",findIndex(sc,testchar));
        printf("Enter the search character: ");
        scanf("%c",&testchar);
                fflush(stdin);
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output was the index of character only one time, but I am getting this:-

```
[amarjeet@amarjeet ~]$ ./a.out 
Enter the search character: Y
The search char found at: 66 position.
The search char found at: 128 position.
Enter the search character: The search char found at: 0 position.
Enter the search character:
```

Where did I go wrong?
Please let me know what is the issue  and how to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with warnings enable (e.g., -Wall)?  I suspect you would see a warning about function return value.

Comment: You'll also get a warning about comparing a `char` with a pointer, specifically "different levels of indirection".

Comment: I debugged your source code.Its also taking the newline character(as you are pressing enter) so its printing 2 times.

Comment: Thanks every body for comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one warning in your code which must be corrected

```
while((test = array[count]) != NULL)
```

The above line generates warning: **comparison between pointer and integer**.Therefore should be corrected as

```
while((test = array[count])!='\0')
```

In your output you are getting the index of character twice because **newline character** is also taken and its position is also getting printed(As you are pressing enter).

To avoid this you can do this

```
while(testchar != 'N')
{
       if(testchar!='\n'){//checking whether character is newline
        printf("The search char %d found at: %d posotion.\n",testchar,findIndex(sc,testchar));
        printf("Enter the search character: ");
        scanf("%c",&testchar);

        }
        else
        {
             scanf("%c",&testchar);//reading the newline character but not performing any operation(printing the index )
        }

}
```

Thats it your program works now.

Note:Use of fflush(stdin)is considered a bad practice and has undefined behaviour.Its better not to use it for flushing input streams as its unportable.See this more information [Do not use fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

**Output**

```
Enter the search character: Y
The search char found at: 66 position.
The search char 89 found at: 128 position.
Enter the search character: J
The search char 74 found at: 0 position.
Enter the search character: o
The search char 111 found at: 85 position.
Enter the search character: N
```

Hope it helps.Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the main function to look like this:

```
int main()
{
    char sc[] = "cn:Y,x509UniqueIdentifier:Y,pseudonym:Y,name:Y,l:Y,street:Y,state:Y,postalAddress:Y,postalCode:Y,telephoneNumber:Y,emailAddress:Y";
    char testchar;

    printf("Enter the search character: ");
    scanf("%c",&testchar);
    while(testchar != '\n' && getchar() != '\n'); # discard any next chars

    while(testchar != 'N') {
        printf("The search char found at: %d position.\n",findIndex(sc,testchar));
        printf("Enter the search character: ");
        scanf("%c",&testchar);
        while(testchar != '\n' && getchar() != '\n'); # discard any next chars
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above example produces the result:

```
$ > ./a.out
Enter the search character: Y
The search char found at: 66 position.
Enter the search character: .
The search char found at: 0 position.
Enter the search character: ,
The search char found at: 83 position.
Enter the search character: g
The search char found at: 0 position.
Enter the search character: N
$ >
```

PS: fflush() is not defined by ISO for input streams. It is defined in Microsoft's C runtime library, but is not portable.